# Redis server not starting - Forked Process did not respond in a timely manner

Tags: redis

Redis server which was working fine got stopped suddenly and the error is:

```
BeginForkOperation: system error caught. error code=0x00000000, message=Forked 
Process did not respond in a timely manner.
```

Not able to figure out why it is happening, and also when I am restarting my machine then 
if I start the redis-server it's working fine.

Please help me in this regard.

Comment: Which version of Redis are you using? What operating system are you using? Do you get any other error messages, or any other hints as to what happened?

Comment: Windows, redis 2.8.4 and not getting any other error.

Answer (score 0):

You should try updating your Redis version, the guys from MSOpenTech fixed a lot of bugs in the last months and this one looks related, at least the error message is identical: https://github.com/MSOpenTech/redis/issues/144